# yaw angle from xyz measurement

Tags: linear-algebra

I have 2 measurement vectors from measurement points, mV1 and mV2. Every measurement point vector contains a x, y and z signal strength. The measurement points are distanced exactly 1000mm only in the y-direction.

[image: here a small image of the setup]

As you can see, I figured out the lengths of the vectors between the sensor and the measurement points. If the pose of the sensor equals the pose of the world coordinates, I can figure out the x and y vectors using Pythagoras' theorem.

How do I figure out the x and y vector if there is a yaw angle in the sensor?

[image: the yaw angle on the sensor]

The known vector mV1

$$
\begin{matrix}
 & 0.6900 \\
10^{-5} * & 0.6597\\
& -0.8069
\end{matrix}
$$

The known vector mV2

$$
\begin{matrix}
 & 0.3134 \\
10^{-6} * & 0.5900\\
& -0.1014
\end{matrix}
$$

The (unknown) matrix M with ypr(20,0,0) and t(200,200,0)
$$
\begin{matrix}
0.4081 & -0.3726 & 0.8335 & 7.1051 \\
0.9129 & 0.1665 & -0.3726 & 215.89 \\
0 & 0.9129 & 0.4081 & 182.5891 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

MATLAB code to get from the matrix to the measurement (with explanation):

```
dist = 1000; % distance between the measurement points
mV2 = mV1 * tM('t',[0,dist,0]); %integrating the distance in the second mV
mV1 = null(M(1:3,3:4)')/sum(M(1:3,4).^2); %getting the first 3 lines of the 2 rightmost columns, swapping lines and columns, determine the null space, so that M * x = 0. We divide the nullspace by the sum of the squared position
mV1 = mV1.*-sign(det([M(1:3,3:4) mV1])) % defining the det(a scalar) and swap the sign if det is positive
mV2 = null(M(1:3,3:4)')/sum(sW2P(1:3,4).^2); %same for mV2
mV2 = mV2.*-sign(det([M(1:3,3:4) mV2]))
```